# Kafka Stops consuming message after multiple failures

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We have a simple application. One micro service will send messages to be consumed by two other micro services. Of the two services, one is able to successfully process the messages and we don't see a lag there. The other service consistently fails and after 25th message no other message is consumed. Is there a reason for this?

The Kafka topic is created with one partition and one replication factor.

**Service 1 - Working Fine:**
[Service Working Fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyh0E.png)

**Service 2 - Lag increasing:**
[Lag Increasing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUhBp.png)

Is there a configuration in Kafka that will make the consumer to stop consuming the messages after a particular amount of failure or what can we do to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Most likely the thread is "stuck" in user code; enable debug logging and take a thread dump to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

you are saying a topic with one partition and you have two different services, I'm assuming *different consumer groups names* consuming from the same topic partition, one service is consuming fine and other one stop consuming at 25th message. In this case you can check in that consumer logs why it is not consuming, this could be malformed message where the consumer is able to consume.

here is how I'd debug

1. restart or redeploy the same consumer and see it is alway stop at 25th message
2. if step 1 is true, check 24th and 25th message and see the difference or reset offset to 26th to see, if consumer is moving forward after offset reset, then message 25th having some issue where consumer unable to consume.